# Delegate nullptr parameter to the pointer overload in template code

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, nullptr

Consider the code below:

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename T> // generic
void f(T)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

template<typename T> // overload for pointer types
void f(T*)
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
    int* p{nullptr};
    f(p);       // correct delegation to f<T*>();
    f(nullptr); // calls f<T>();
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c17291c6b7e55b8)

As you can see, calling `f(nullptr)` results in the generic `f(T)` being called, and not the pointer overload `f(T*)`. This is quite annoying. I know why this happens: because `nullptr` is of type [`std::nullptr_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/nullptr_t), and the generic template has a higher overload rank.

How can I "solve" this issue in a straightforward manner? I can of course write two different implementations, one for pointers and one for `nullptr_t`, then have a generic one that dispatches to one of the two via some SFINAE, but this looks a bit too complicated.

Comment: How can you expect the `T*` overload to be called when `std::nullptr_t` has no type that it points to? I think you really need separate logic for that case anyway, so you might as well add a third overload.

Comment: @Brian I don't expect `f(T*)` to be called, I'd like to obtain this behaviour without too much trouble.

Comment: What do you expect `T` to be when you call `f(T*)`?

Comment: What I meant was what @cicto said. Thanks for saying it better than I could.

Comment: Ohh I see what you mean... This is indeed a good point I didn't think about. So it looks like a third overload is the way to go.

Comment: @cicto Playing devil's advocate for a second: it would not be unreasonable for it to be `void`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way would probably be to implement an overload `void f(std::nullptr_t)`, and dispatch to one of the pointer implementations, which can be chosen by you, assuming it does the right thing (whatever the right thing is) for null pointers:

```
void f(std::nullptr_t) { f(static_cast<void *>(nullptr)); }
```